# How connection pooling can be implemented in Wordpress?

Tags: mysql

I have been facing issues with High connection count on mysql DB and therefore suggested to have connection pooling implementation. I did a lot of research but finding solution for different tech like Java but not finding anything specific related to wordpress. So can anyone help me on this?